# p:selectManyMenu(with checkbox): Add item and select checkbox at the same time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

xhtml code

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="menuid"
                value="#{bean.selectedActivities}"
                showCheckbox="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150">
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.activities}" var="activity" itemValue="#{activity}"
                               itemLabel="#{activity}" />               
</p:selectManyMenu>
<p:commandButton value="ADD ACTIVITY" id="addId">
    <p:ajax event="click" process="@this" update="menuid" listener="#{bean.addActivity()}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Bean:

```
private List<String> selectedActivities = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> activities = new ArrayList<>();
int index = 1;
public void addActivity(){
  String activity = "Activity "+ (index ++);
  activities.add(activity);
  selectedActivities.add(activity);
}
```

This code is adding new item to the manyMenu but the checkbox is not selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from some missing annotations I don't see much wrong. In any case, here is a tested solution based on your code that should work. First let's define the view. This is basically the same as in your example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>SelectMany Example</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:selectManyMenu id="menuid"
                      value="#{selectManyBackingBean.selectedActivities}"
                      showCheckbox="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150">
                <f:selectItems value="#{selectManyBackingBean.activities}" var="activity" itemValue="#{activity}"
                           itemLabel="#{activity}" />               
            </p:selectManyMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="ADD ACTIVITY" id="addId">
                <p:ajax event="click" process="@form" update="menuid"
                    listener="#{selectManyBackingBean.onAddActivity}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Then, we define the backing bean:

```
@Data
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SelectManyBackingBean implements Serializable {
    private List<String> selectedActivities;
    private List<String> activities;
    private int index;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        activities =  new ArrayList<>();
        selectedActivities = new ArrayList<>();
        index = 0;
    }

    public void onAddActivity(){
        String activity = "Activity " + (index++);
        activities.add(activity);
        selectedActivities.add(activity);
    }
}
```

This should give you the expected behavior. Clicking three times on the *ADD ACTIVITY* button now yields the following result:

[image]

Notice the subtle change in the command button from `process="@this"` to `process="@form"`. This will make sure that any changes you make in the component are also included in the form submission. If you keep it at the original value, any clicks on the check boxes in the menu will not be kept and will reset entries to the previous value when you press the command button (this is because the component in question is not included when the life cycle executes).

Comment: Auto selection is not working when having another field on the page under the control. I updated the code, added newField1 field. Can you help me with this please

Comment: @gvg: this is a new question, please ceeate one